# Multiple Table Update using Stored Procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, webforms, sql-update

I'm getting the following error:

> "Procedure or function 'USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM has too many
>   arguments specified"

I have read A LOT of post regarding this topic and implemented many of the `fixes` but I'm still seeing the same error.  Can anyone PLEASE help me out?

I have a form that updates 3 separate tables when an update button is selected.  I have chosen to perform this operation by using a `store procedure in the SQL Database`. The stored procedure and asp form code.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks! Kelly

SQL Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM]
        @CUSTOMER_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(150),
        @CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(150),
        @CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME VARCHAR(150),
        @CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_STORE_ID INT,
        @CUSTOMER_BDC_REP_ID INT,
        @ADDRESS_LINE_1 VARCHAR(150),
        @ADDRESS_CITY VARCHAR(150),
        @ADDRESS_STATE VARCHAR(150),
        @ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE VARCHAR(150),
        @PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(30),
        @PHONE_NUMBER_2 VARCHAR(30),
        @PHONE_NUMBER_3 VARCHAR(30)



AS
    BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = @CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME,
        CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME = @CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME,
        CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = @CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME,
        CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID = @CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID,
        CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID = @CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID,
        CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID = @CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID,
        CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID = @CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID,
        CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID = @CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID,
        CUSTOMER_STORE_ID = @CUSTOMER_STORE_ID,
        CUSTOMER_BDC_REP_ID = @CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID

    WHERE 
        CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID;

    UPDATE CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
    SET ADDRESS_LINE_1 = @ADDRESS_LINE_1,
        ADDRESS_CITY = @ADDRESS_CITY,
        ADDRESS_STATE = @ADDRESS_STATE,
        ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE = @ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE
    WHERE
        ADDRESS_CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID
        AND ADDRESS_SEQ_NUMBER = 
        (SELECT MAX(B.ADDRESS_SEQ_NUMBER)
        FROM CUSTOMER_ADDRESS B
        WHERE B.ADDRESS_CUSTOMER_ID = ADDRESS_CUSTOMER_ID);


    UPDATE CUSTOMER_PHONE
    SET PHONE_NUMBER = @PHONE_NUMBER,
        PHONE_NUMBER_2 = @PHONE_NUMBER_2,
        PHONE_NUMBER_3 = @PHONE_NUMBER_3
    WHERE
        PHONE_CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID
        AND PHONE_SEQ_NUMBER = 
        (SELECT MAX(B.PHONE_SEQ_NUMBER)
        FROM CUSTOMER_PHONE B
        WHERE B.PHONE_CUSTOMER_ID = PHONE_CUSTOMER_ID);

END
```

ASPX Form Code:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="CUSTOMER_CONTACT_INFO" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS_CUSTOMER_CONTACT1" Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#1F497D" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; margin-top: 0px;" Width="1000px"              DefaultMode="Edit" DataKeyNames="CUSTOMER_ID" Height="268px" EditRowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            CUSTOMER:&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Enabled="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_NUMBER", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME" runat="server" 
                AutoCompleteType="FirstName" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" 
                ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME", "{0}")%>' Width="100px" 
                CausesValidation="True" />
&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME" runat="server" 
                AutoCompleteType="MiddleName" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" 
                ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME", "{0}")%>' Width="75px" CausesValidation="True" />
&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="LastName" 
                AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" 
                Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME", "{0}")%>' 
                Width="100px" CausesValidation="True" Wrap="False" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PHONE:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="PHONE_NUMBERTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#0070C0" 
                Text='<%# Bind("PHONE_NUMBER", "{0}")%>' Width="100px" Font-Underline="True" />
&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="PHONE_ALT1_NUMBERTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#0070C0" 
                Text='<%# Bind("PHONE_NUMBER_2", "{0}")%>' Width="100px" Font-Underline="True" />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="PHONE_ALT2_NUMBERTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#0070C0" 
                Text='<%# Bind("PHONE_NUMBER_3", "{0}")%>' Width="100px" Font-Underline="True" />
            <br />
            ADDRESS:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="ADDRESS_LINE_1" runat="server" 
                AutoCompleteType="HomeStreetAddress" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" 
                ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("ADDRESS_LINE_1", "{0}")%>' Width="283px" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="ADDRESS_CITY" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="HomeCity" 
                AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" 
                Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" 
                Text='<%# Bind("ADDRESS_CITY", "{0}")%>' />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="STATETextBox" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="HomeState" 
                AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" 
                Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("ADDRESS_STATE", "{0}")%>' 
                Width="25px" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="ZIPCODETextBox" runat="server" 
                AutoCompleteType="HomeZipCode" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" 
                ForeColor="#0070C0" Text='<%# Bind("ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE", "{0}")%>' Width="73px" />
            &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_ID")%>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<hr align="left" noshade="noshade" size="2" 
        style="border-color: #1F497D; color: #1F497D" width="1000" /><span class="style2">STATUS:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="STATUS_RADIO_BUTTON" runat="server" CssClass="visibility:hidden" DataSourceID="DS_VAL_STATUS_TYPE_TABLE" DataTextField="VAL_STATUS_DESC" DataValueField="VAL_STATUS_ID" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#A6A6A6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID", "{0}")%>' Enabled="False" Height="25px">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_VAL_STATUS_TYPE_TABLE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [VAL_STATUS] ORDER BY [VAL_STATUS_SORT_ORDER]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <span class="style2">
            <br />
            PROGRESS:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="PROGRESS_RADIO_BUTTON" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS_VAL_PROGRESS_TABLE" DataTextField="VAL_PROGRESS_DESC" DataValueField="VAL_PROGRESS_ID" Enabled="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#A6A6A6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID", "{0}")%>' Height="25px">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_VAL_PROGRESS_TABLE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [VAL_PROGRESS] ORDER BY [VAL_PROGRESS_SORT_ORDER]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <hr align="left" noshade="noshade" size="2" 
        style="border-color: #1F497D; color: #1F497D" width="1000" />
            <span class="style2">CONTROL:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="CONTROL_RADIO_BUTTON" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="DS_VAL_CONTROL_TABLE" DataTextField="VAL_CONTROL_DESC" DataValueField="VAL_CONTROL_ID" Enabled="False" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#A6A6A6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID", "{0}")%>'>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#1F497D" Text="BDC REP:"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoDSFPostBack="True" DataSourceID="DS_BDC_DROP_DOWN_VALIDATION" DataTextField="EMP_FULL_NAME" DataValueField="EMP_ID" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_BDC_REP_ID", "{0}")%>' Width="200px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_BDC_DROP_DOWN_VALIDATION" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DEAL_USER_ID AS EMP_ID, DEAL_USER_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + DEAL_USER_LAST_NAME AS EMP_FULL_NAME, DEAL_USER_FIRST_NAME AS EMP_FIRST, DEAL_USER_LAST_NAME AS EMP_LAST FROM ADMIN_EMPLOYEE_USER ORDER BY DEAL_USER_FIRST_NAME, DEAL_USER_LAST_NAME"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#1F497D" Text="STORE: "></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoDSFPostBack="True" CssClass="HideArrow" DataSourceID="DS_STORE_DROP_DOWN_VALIDATION" DataTextField="VAL_STORE_LOCATION" DataValueField="VAL_STORE_ID" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_STORE_ID", "{0}")%>' Width="200px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_STORE_DROP_DOWN_VALIDATION" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [VAL_STORE_ID], [VAL_STORE_LOCATION] FROM [VAL_STORE] ORDER BY [VAL_STORE_LOCATION]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_VAL_CONTROL_TABLE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [VAL_CONTROL] ORDER BY [VAL_CONTROL_SORT_ORDER]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <hr align="left" noshade="noshade" size="2" 
        style="border-color: #1F497D; color: #1F497D" width="1000" />
            <span class="style2">INITIAL CONTACT:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="INITIAL_CONTACT_RADIO_BUTTON" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="DS_VAL_INITIAL_CONTATCT_TABLE" DataTextField="VAL_INITIAL_CONTACT_DESC" DataValueField="VAL_INITIAL_CONTACT_ID" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID", "{0}")%>' Height="25px">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_VAL_INITIAL_CONTATCT_TABLE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [VAL_INITIAL_CONTACT] ORDER BY [VAL_INITIAL_CONTACT_DESC]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <span class="style2">
            <br />
            AD SOURCE:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="STATUS_RADIO_BUTTON0" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="DS_VAL_AD_SOURCE_TABLE" DataTextField="VAL_AD_SOURCE_DESC" DataValueField="VAL_AD_SOURCE_ID" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0070C0" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID", "{0}")%>' Height="25px">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

            <hr align="left" noshade="noshade" size="2" 
        style="border-color: #1F497D; color: #1F497D" width="1000" />

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_VAL_AD_SOURCE_TABLE" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [VAL_AD_SOURCE] ORDER BY [VAL_AD_SOURCE_DESC]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="text-align: center" Width="1000px">
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="UPDATE" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#1F497D" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" CssClass="static" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#1F497D" CommandArgument="USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM" PostBackUrl="~/Customer_Contact.aspx" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </EditItemTemplate>

<EditRowStyle VerticalAlign="Top"></EditRowStyle>

    </asp:FormView>


  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_CUSTOMER_CONTACT1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DS_FreedomRidesConnect %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID) AS CUSTOMER_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUMBER) AS CUSTOMER_NUMBER, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME) + ' ' + MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME) + ' ' + MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAME, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, MAX(CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER) AS PHONE_NUMBER, MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_LINE_1 IS NOT NULL AND ADDRESS_CITY IS NOT NULL AND ADDRESS_STATE IS NOT NULL AND ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN ADDRESS_LINE_1 + ',   ' + ADDRESS_CITY + ',   ' + ADDRESS_STATE + ',  ' + ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE END) AS FULL_ADDRESS, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_1, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CITY, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_STATE, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE, MAX(CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_ID) AS Expr1, MAX(CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID) AS Expr2, CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER_2, CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER_3, CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_ACTIVE_IND, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ACTIVE_IND, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID) AS CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID) AS CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID) AS CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID) AS CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID) AS CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_STORE_ID) AS CUSTOMER_STORE_ID, MAX(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_BDC_REP_ID) AS CUSTOMER_BDC_REP_ID FROM CUSTOMER LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_PHONE ON CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID AND CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y' LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ON CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID AND CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y' GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE_1, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CITY, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_STATE, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE, CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER_2, CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_NUMBER_3, CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_ACTIVE_IND, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ACTIVE_IND HAVING (CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = @Cust_ID) AND (CUSTOMER_PHONE.PHONE_ACTIVE_IND = N'Y') AND (CUSTOMER_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ACTIVE_IND = N'Y')" 

        UpdateCommand="USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="100003" FormField="CUST_ID" Name="CUST_ID" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
           <%-- <asp:Parameter Name="CUSTOMER_ID" Type="Int32" />--%>
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_MIDDLE_NAME" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_AD_SOURCE_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_CURRENT_CONTROL_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_CURRENT_STATUS_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_CURRENT_PROGRESS_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_INITIAL_CONTACT_TYPE_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_STORE_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="CUSTOMER_BDC_REP_ID" Type="Int32" />

            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="ADDRESS_LINE_1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="ADDRESS_CITY" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="ADDRESS_STATE" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="ADDRESS_ZIP_CODE" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="PHONE_NUMBER" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="PHONE_NUMBER_2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Input" Name="PHONE_NUMBER_3" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually occurring from the fact that the parameters passed into the stored procedure upon execution (`exec USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM`)  is not the same number as the number of parameters in the stored procedure parameter list.  Because they are different, an error occurs.  That's usually what the error entails.

Comment: I understand.  There are 18 parameters in each though.  That is why I am so confused.

Comment: Well, you are using a data source, so maybe it's not passing all 18.  It could be doing something funky...  Shouldn't be, but possible.  Not sure how to tell you to debug, other than tap into the Updating event on the SQS, and check the number of values provided in the values collection on the event argument, which are all of the parameters that will be passed to the proc.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around: 
In your aspx form page, replace the Bind("FieldName') with Eval("FieldName"), since every Bound field in the FormView is passed to the Update procedure.


Another one you can try:
in sqldatasource(*DS_CUSTOMER_CONTACT1*) instead of `UpdateCommand="USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"` 

try with 
`UpdateCommand="Exec USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM" UpdateCommandType="Text"`

Comment: The UpdateCommand="Exec USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM" UpdateCommandType="Text" took care of the 'too many arguments error, but it is now giving me a "Procedure or function 'USP_UPDATE_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_FORM' expects parameter '@CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME', which was not supplied. " error.

Comment: So it is not recognizing the parameters being passed into the store procedure.  When I changed the 'Type' back to 'Stored Procedure' the Exec has to be removed.